# how to find out only one digit in a int number?

Tags: math, integer

Im new so if this question was already Asked (i didnt find it scrolling through the list of results though) please send me the link.

I got a math quiz and im to lazy to go through all the possibilities so i thought i can find a program instead. I know a bit about programming but not much.

Is it possible (and in what programming language, and how)  to read only one digit, e.g at the 3rd Position, in a integer?
And how is an integer actually saved, in a kind of array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of any lower valued digit (the ones and tens if you only want the hundreds) by dividing with rounding/truncation. `1234/100` is 12 in most languages if you are doing integer division.
You can get rid of any higher valued digits  by using taking the modulus. `12 % 10` is 2 in many languages; just find out how the modulus is done in yours. I use "modulus" meaning "divide and keep the rest only", i.e. it is the opposite of "divide with rounding"; that which is lost by rounding is the final result of the modulus.

The alternative is however to actually NOT see the input as a number and treat it as text. That way it is often easier to ignore the last 2 characters and all leading characters.

Comment: Which part do you want explained in more detail?

Comment: I got to google the modulus...

Comment: Hmm, I hope I got the English word right. I will also search to confirm. Seems I got it not too wrong. But I will explain in the answer.

Comment: So, you say that i can just divide the whole number by ten and the modulus is the digit it ends on? And if i want the 2nd digit of a 4 digit divided by 100?

Comment: Please give example inputs, each with desired result. Consider doing that by editing the question.

Comment: Yeah im sorry im not first language english. I got the second part now.

Comment: Input 1234, result 4; 1534->4; 6473->3

Comment: `1234%10` is 4, `1534%10` is 4, `6473%10` is 3; in e.g. C, C++. Or some string-oriented function to ignore all but the last character.